# Bootstrap and "Contact Us" form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i'm using bootstrap template "rockline business" http://webthemez.com/free-bootstrap-template-rockline-business/ and can't figure out how to 
1) enable the "contact us" form 
2) find the location/file(s) where to input my email into the "contact us" form (as the receiver of form data)

Thanks in advance for any answers or insight.
-Josh

Comment: you need a server side language "to enable" it. getting data from user and pass it to you.

Comment: marmeladze 3, thanks. do you know which server side language, or where this would be located in respect to the folders contained in the template, "js", "flexslider", "css"?

Comment: there are a lot of scripting and programming languages possesses server side processing abilities, perl, asp, php also python, ruby, scala, groovy, java, c#. you can choose any of them for your taste.  

if you intend to use php, which more suits to your situation, no need to make a distinct folder for this. just mix it with your html code. you can find an example here  - http://www.123contactform.com/simple-php-contact-form.html  
or for better - http://www.123contactform.com/jquery-contact-form.htm

Comment: Marmeladze, thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need some sort of server side code associated with the form. Possibly using ajax request to submit the data in the form to be processed and sent out. PHP or nodejs+nodemailer or a slew of others would do the trick. Here is an [example](https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-freelancer) of a similar contact form wired up to a php backend.

Comment: zzrot, thanks. would this be a viable solution? switching templates to the example (freelancer), opening mail-contact_me.php, editing line 23, and switching "$email_address" to "my_email@address"?

Comment: I don't believe so. Line 19 in mail-contact_me.php is where the email from the contact form will be sent to. Also if you do not desire to use php I have an example on [my git-hub](https://github.com/zzrot/forjd310) using nodejs with node mailer but the same front end from the template. I used the template I showed you for my portfolio but instead of using the php mailer I wired up some js code using Node.js and nodemailer. [Here is a link](http://codeforgeek.com/2014/07/send-e-mail-node-js/) to the article that I used to learn how to user Nodemailer in Node.js.